# Can't find session while calling for the second time using android

Tags: php, android, facebook, session

In my application I am trying to retreve data from server using api.Since I was trying to get the facebook data I am passing facebookid when i call the url for the first time.The code is suchthat it should get data from the server when another url is called.

My problem is that I am getting a null value when I call the url for the second time.That is here the session is getting deleted.
My code is given below.

```
public void getdetails(){
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(unielement+"UserLogin.php?faceid="+facebookID);
    System.out.println(unielement+"UserLogin.php?faceid="+facebookID+"   "+json);

    try{
        JSONArray  data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        //Loop the Array
        for(int i=0;i < data.length();i++){                      

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("CreditBySelf"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("CreditThroughFriend"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("ForUser"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("LDrawTicket"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("Buy-In"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("RemVote"));
            list.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("Voted"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : list)
            {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\t");
            }
            uid = list.get(0);
            name = list.get(1).toString();
            System.out.println(list);
            textView_name1.setText(name);

        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No name Found"+e1 ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I call the above function a session is created and it should be there when I call the below code.

```
public void getdataforsharing(){

    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(unielement+"userfbaction.php");
    System.out.println(unielement+"userfbaction.php    "+json);

    try{
        JSONArray  wholedata = json.getJSONArray("data");
        System.out.println(wholedata);
        JSONObject  data = wholedata.getJSONObject(0);
        System.out.println(data);
        //Loop the Array
        for(int i=0;i < data.length();i++){                      

            list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            /*list1.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("wall_image"));
            list1.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("wall_title"));
            list1.add(data.getJSONObject(0).getString("wall_Description"));*/
            list1.add(data.getString("wall_image"));
            list1.add(data.getString("wall_title"));
            list1.add(data.getString("wall_Description"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : list1)
            {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\t");
            }
            System.out.println("Share on facebook"+list1.get(0));
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No name Found"+e1 ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I call this function I am not getting the session that is created by the first funcion and I am getting a null data.

What is wrong in this?Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is created in "UserLogin.php".

Sessions are controlled in PHP by use of a SessionID which can be either:

1. passed as a query parameter; you need to receive the session ID, then add to the URL next time you call, or
2. passed in a cookie; you need to receive the cookie, then send the cookie to the URL next time you call.

Your code is doing neither: you're only accepted the JSON back, you're not reading in the cookie and sending next time, nor are you receiving a SessionID in the data and using it with the next call.

---

Easiest solution in your case:

1. In the first call, return the contents of "session_id()" as part of your json. Remember it for later, store in memory or in a file - however you need it.
2. In the second call to userfbaction.php, send that session_id as a parameter
3. In userfbaction.php, read the parameter and call "session_id()" passing in the session_id before session_start(). This will then continue the previous session